# Forcing text to go around a 'close window' button in CSS

Tags: html, css

In [this page](http://goo.gl/XmgmrX), if you click on a job title, it will open up a blue window containing a job summary, with a 'close window' button in the upper right corner. The 'close' button often overlaps the text of the job summary. I'd like to force the text to go around the 'close' button, so that there is no overlap.

The 'close' button consists of a span (containing a bootstrap glyph) within a div. The CSS code for the elements is as follows:

```
.div__job_grid_summary_close_button {
    background-color: #f9f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 24px;
}

.div__job_grid_summary_close_button span {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 1.42px 0 0 2.2px;
}
.glyphicon {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

What's the best way to make the text go around the 'close' button? Thank you.

Comment: The way you have your html laid out, not directly.  You could either change the close div to have the same parent and display them as inline-blocks, or, more easily, add a padding-right of abut 35px to class div__job_grid_summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is using

`position:absolute;`

Soo, remove that. Change it to:

```
float:right; margin:9px;
```

Edit: Margin is just a suggestion, set it to whatever you'd like.

Comment: Yep, that takes care of it. Thanks!